# Store data in array - then iterate that array

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net

I have a list of items that is not fixed. It can vary between 3 and 8. what I'm trying to do is loop through to find out how many items I have - then store these items in an array so that they are in reverse order and HIDE them. Then I'd like to go back into that Array and SHOW them.

Something along these lines.

```
For ix As Integer = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    Dim frm = Application.OpenForms(ix)
    Dim arList() As String = {frm.Name}
    frm.Hide()
Next
```

So as far as I am concerned the items are getting saved in the array, it doesn't give any errors and each time it goes through the loop it shows a corresponding item when I hove over {frm.Name}

How would I be able to loop through this array something like...

```
 for each ItemName as string in arList()
      if itemName <> "" then
         do something
      End if
 Next
```

Comment: *That* `arList` can only ever hold one item since you redeclare it for each item in the loop.  Since it is declared with block scope it wont exist outside the For loop.   You should also know that `Application.OpenForms` has been known to "forget" forms

Comment: I don't know VB but you probably ought to use a `List<string>` from `System.Collections.Generics` and then perform `myList.add(frm.name)` to add items. Then iterate through it with a `for each` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some fundamental things wrong with the code:

```
For ix As Integer = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    Dim frm = Application.OpenForms(ix)
    Dim arList() As String = {frm.Name}
    frm.Hide()
Next
```

`Dim` declares a new variable with the `Scope` depending on *where* it is declared.  So,

1. your code is declaring a new `arList` for each form, replacing the previous.
2. it can only ever hold one form name (the last one encountered)
3. since it is declared *inside* a `For/Each` block it will only exist there.  This is called `Block` scope: everything which results in code indendation creates a new `Block Scope`

Avoid arrays unless they are to hold some static set of data (eg `Dim foo As String() = {"red", "green", "blue"}`.  Lists are much easier to work with, are more flexible and more powerful.

```
' form level list variable
Private myFormNames As List(Of String)
```

Elsewhere when you want to use it:

```
myFormNames = New List(Of String)

For n As Int32 = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    Dim frm = Application.OpenForms(n)
    ' add this name to the list
    myFormNames.Add(frm.Name)
    frm.Hide()
Next
```

I am not sure what value this has since the OpenForms collection should still have the form in it since all you did was hide it:

```
For n As Int32 = 0 To Application.OpenForms.Count - 1
    Dim frm = Application.OpenForms(n)
    If myFormNames.Contains(frm.Name) Then
        ' do something
    End If
Next
```

Note also that the `OpenForms` collection has been known to "forget" forms.  If it is mission critical, you may want to track them yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking to have them in aspecific order. So if I simply check for .openforms -in the first and 2nd FOR loops - I don't know if all forms will be in the same order. Basically with the first loop my goal is to go through the open forms in reverse order - so I can save them in that particular order. In the second loop - rather than LOOPing through open forms, I want to just loop through the array and .SHOW them in the order they were saved In (inside the array). correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I still dont see what role the array/list plays.  Since you hid all the forms showing, you could just loop thru the openForms collection again and `.Show` them -- what makes you think the order would have changed?

Comment: I'm not sure - I want to be sure. Basically the goal of this whole thing (as you probably know since you've helped me with most of my stuff) is to hide all forms, and show them again when user relogs back in. It's just I want to make sure if user last was on Form3 - they expect to see Form3 when they relog back in. Array would assure that they were in that particular order?

Comment: The order in the collection is the order they were created/shown and added to the collection, not the Z-Order.

Comment: In some cases `ActiveForm` might be all you need, but if the app is minimized or not the from app (and maybe if the screensaver is showing) it will be `Nothing`.  You'll may have to track the `LastActiveForm` yourself

Comment: thanks - for now it's working i'll test it in different scenarios.